# how to Insert Store_Id in the products table while importing the product .csv file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, import, medusajs

I am working on medusajs E-commerce project where we have to import the bulk products with the help of the .csv products import file.
but while processing this I want to insert the store_id in the product table
Thanks for the time and consideration.

Please guide me for the same

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.